# I need to create a recursive function that replaces all numbers in a list that are less than n

Tags: python, recursion

An example of what I'm looking for is this: threshold([1, -4, 0, 4, 8], 1) returns [1, 1, 1, 4, 8]. As in the previous problem, the given list can be of any length.

```
def thresHold(l, n):
    if l < [n]:
        return 
    else:
        return thresHold(l[1:])

print(thresHold([1,-5,6,92,56], 10))
```

I currently have this for my code, which I do not even know if it is relatively close to what
I'm trying to do. Recursion is not my strong suit.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“I'm lost” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Why not `[max(threshold, x) for x in lst]`? Recursion is wildly inappropriate here. If you _have_ to use recursion, use indices instead of slicing lists which adds a factor of `n` to the complexity unnecessarily.

Comment: Since you don't even know whether this works, or is close, then you have some work to do before you're ready to post here.  *Test* your code; trace the operation.  If you need help understanding recursion, then work through appropriate on-line materials, or work with a local friend or tutor.  None of this is Stack Overflow material ... but you're getting close.

Comment: The function with just one-line body `return [max(num, lst[0])] + threshold(lst[1:], num) if lst else []` will do the work, but I agree with others that recursion is not quite appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need recursion to solve this, a list comprehension will do:

```py
def threshold(x, v):
    return [max(e, v) for e in x]
    
print(threshold([1, -4, 0, 4, 8], 1))      # Outputs [1, 1, 1, 4, 8]
print(threshold([1, -5, 6, 92, 56], 10))   # Outputs [10, 10, 10, 92, 56]
```